# Why am I getting 'application/json' response instead of 'text/html' using PartialView in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-5, content-type

The action code:

```
public ActionResult Visit(VisitModel model)
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
        return PartialView("VisitPostRedirect", visit);

    // some logic...

    return PartialView(visit);
}
```

The 'VisitPostRedirect' view:

```
@model VisitModel
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body onload="javascript: document.getElementById('visitPostRedirectForm').submit()">
    @using (Html.BeginRouteForm("Visit", new
    {
        // some data...
        RedirectUrl = string.Empty
    }, FormMethod.Post,
    new { id="visitPostRedirectForm" }))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ReturnUrl)
        // some data...
    }
</body>
</html>
```

The 'Visit' view:

```
@model VisitModel
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, , maximum-scale=1.0">

   <!-- ... -->
</head>
<body>
   <!-- ... -->
</html>
```

The 'visitPostRedirectForm' form submits correctly, with:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pl;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:69
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=vh3kl4zbxkonborzazuafkiw
Host: /*removed*/
Origin:/*removed*/
Referer:/*removed*/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
```

but the response is:

```
Cache-Control:private
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:2135
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 04 Jun 2014 09:23:32 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:5.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Has anybody an idea why the content-type of the response is 'application/json'? This causes a browser to render raw html. The returned html is correct.

Comment: Why do you have `doctype`, `html` and `body` in a `PartialView`?

Comment: Because PartialView renders the page without layout. The two views are very specific in my application, so i don't want to use master layout for them.

Comment: I think you're misusing the `PartialView` idea. Use a `View` instead.

Comment: It doesn't matter. I've already tried with View() and @{ Layout = null; }. It works in the same way, with 'application/json' content-type.

Comment: What about using `BeginForm` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx) instead of `BeginRouteForm` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginrouteform(v=vs.118).aspx)?

Comment: I don't use the default route "{controller}/{action}/{id}". All my actions have a dedicated routes with a different url formats, so I have to use BeginRouteForm to get correct url for the form's action attribute.

Comment: I see. I'm running out of options then. :)

Comment: I have found the cause of the issue. Somewhere in the 'Visit' view I included another partial view using @Html.Action(). The included partial view has two methods which handle it: one for HttpGet and one for HttpPost. The HttpPost action returns view using Json() method, so it changes the content-type of the whole response. 

I am so stupid, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No problems. It's good that you found the issue yourself.